# How to Run Tibco BW Activity using JAVA Code Activity in TIBCO BW

Tags: tibco

Is it possible to insert the java code to run a previous activity in the process definition flow ?

For Example: A process definition contains the following items.

```
Start--> ReadFile-> SoapRequestReply -->end
```

In the above example I want to retry the SoapRequestReply activity with the help of java code if the execution of that activity contains any error.

I want to implement the logic in a generic way... I know the said concept can be implemented with the help of "REPEAT ON ERROR UNTILL TRUE" Group but I want to do it with the help of java code. so the new process definition would look like this.

```
Start--> ReadFile-> SoapRequestReply --exception-->RetryOnce(Java Code) --> end..
```

The Java Code will execute the Previous activity one more time.

Please suggest...

Comment: Why does it have to be in a java activity? What is actual problem you are trying to solve (as opposed to the problem with your desired solution)?

Answer (score 3):

This is, indeed, a perfect fit for an error group. But if you **really** can't afford to use one, you could create a SubProcess that calls back your MainProcess on error and hold the retry count in a Job Shared Variable. Please note that this is a quick and dirty workaround.

[image: MainProcess]
[image: SubProcess]

Comment: Nice Logic man, But i just want to repeat the activity in which i am getting the error . I don't want to repeat the whole process.  Let me explain you why i want to repeat only a single activity. Suppose there are two activities in the process definition on which i wish to implement the "retry one more time" logic. In that case the logic you have described is not going to work.So i want to use Java Code or some other logic that could serve the purpose

Comment: In the scenario you described in the OP, this solution will work. The price to pay is reading the file each time, that is why I called it a Q&D workaround. But if you want to be able to replay ONLY the activity that failed, then things get a little trickier and I am not sure you can achieve this in Java. Typical replay mechanisms leverage checkpoints or JMS queues but then all activities located "after" the save point will be replayed, not only the failing one...

Comment: Yeah i want to retry only those activity/Activities that failed.Any suggestion how can i implement it ?

Comment: @user3332463 There are no public API sin BusinessWorks that will allow you to apply "retry one more time" logic to activity.

Comment: @user3332463 Did you consider using Nicolas' answer for each of the activities you want to repeat. Take out the activity into a sub-process and then implement something similar to what Nicolas mentioned.

Comment: Ummmm I wanted to see that whether we can use java code activity to run other activities(At will) in the process definition, But i think its not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by simply surround the SoapRequestReply with a Group.
This could be either a "Repeat on Error until true" group that repeats
by condition x times if an error occurs or a "while true" loop with individual
handling (error transition) e.g. for logging purposes.

No Java Coding  / Activities needed.

With best regards
               Seb

Comment: I want to implement it except using "Group" function. Either by Java code activity or some other way . Can we do it except using "group"?

Comment: See Nicolas solution above ;) However, what's the reason you want to avoid a group?